# Change "reply with message" text

Tags: iphone, messages, text

I know how to change text for RELY WITH MESSAGE option, however 
"Can't talk right now" part can't be changed in setting.

Is there an app or a modification that can change "Can't talk right now" part?

To change text for RELY WITH MESSAGE OPTION go to

- Settings->Phone->Reply with Message

Comment: I don't fully understand. When I go to the indicated menu and tap on one of the stock replies, I can enter in a custom one and it seems to overwrite it.

Comment: You can customize the body of reply message but you can't customize the begging of reply message " Can't talk right now "

Answer (score 1):

If your device is jailbroken, you can use this solution to [change the default reply message prefix](http://modmyi.com/forums/file-mods/818341-change-default-reply-message-prefix.html):

> iFile will let you edit the .plist strings. How ever you do it, the .plist file is in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities/English.Iproj folder (if you use English. What I don't know is if this changes anything in the sent text